# How to convert the image title to a slug and save it to the Database? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

A user can upload an `image` and I want to catch the provided `$request` image title and convert it to a `slug` and save it to the `Database`

UploadScreenShotController@upload:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    if (!auth()->check()) return $this->with('error', 'Session has ended. Please refresh the page and try again.');

    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $image = $request->image;
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $request->image->move(public_path('images/tcpa/screenshots'), $filename);

    return back()
        ->with('success', 'You have successfully uploaded an image.')
        ->with('image', $filename);
}
```

My form:

```
        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'files' => 'true', 'route' => ['admin.sms.tcpa-upload-screenshot']])!!}
            {!! Form::file('image') !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Upload File') !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This `function` gets the `image` name, but it doesn't convert it to a `slug` and it doesn't save in the `Database`.

How to convert the `image` title to a `slug` and save it to the `Database`?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-slug

Answer (score 1):

put `'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'`

```
  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'files' => 'true','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'route' => ['admin.sms.tcpa-upload-screenshot']])!!}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sluggable package to create slug in your project. This package provides a trait that will generate a unique slug when saving any Eloquent model.

Installation
    You can install the package via composer:

```
`composer require spatie/laravel-sluggable`
```

Here's an example of how to implement the trait:

```
 namespace App;
 use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
 use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class YourEloquentModel extends Model
 {
   use HasSlug;
    /**
     * Get the options for generating the slug.
    */
     public function getSlugOptions() : SlugOptions
      {
         return SlugOptions::create()
              ->generateSlugsFrom('name')
              ->saveSlugsTo('slug');
      }
 }
```

And also remember to add a slug field into you database table. Use Laravel Migration to edit your current Table.

Example ::

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateYourEloquentModelTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('your_eloquent_models', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('slug'); // Field name same as your `saveSlugsTo`
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

}
```

And then if you want to use this slug as route name, remember to use Laravel's implicit route model binding in your model file:

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

I think it will help you

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it using the `boot` method in your model.

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class YourEloquentModel extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->slug = Str::slug($model->name, '-');
        });
    }
}
```

The rest of the things you can follow as [@NIVED KRISHNA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9692283/nived-krishna) showed his answer; Like: migration, route model binding.